# SELECT COUNT(*) based on joined table conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, ssms

I'm trying to write a query in relation to an educational system that returns number values based on the below types of inspections done on specific schools in November, only I can't quite make sense of how to do it.

I need to return a list of organizations cited for non-compliance in November, then return type of visit counts within that month that lead to the citation. I need a count for each type from the insp.Type_of_Visit__c conditional based on each provider, but not on distinct provider in case they were issued multiple non-compliances.

**I need each type of visit to be a separate column.**

So far, my in-line subquery is returning unfiltered results:

```
SELECT ...
, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Inspection__c WHERE Type_of_Visit__c = 'Pre-Licensing') AS [Number of PreLicensing Statement of Non-Compliance issue date]
```

That doesn't filter on the WHERE clauses that I have in place.

Also, I would need to repeat that line for each type of visit unless there is a better way to do it.

Honestly, I'm just blanking as to how to properly do this.

```
SELECT  a.Provider_Number__c AS [Provider ID]
, a.Provider_No__c AS [Legacy System Number]
, a.License_Status__c AS [License Status]
, a.Record_Type_Name__c AS [Record Type Name]
, a.Provider_Status__c AS [Provider Status]
, a.License_Type__c AS [License Type]
, a.Name AS [Name]
, a.Provider_Address_1__c AS [Street Address 1]
, a.Provider_Address_2__c AS [Street Address 2]
, a.Provider_city_text__c AS City
, a.Provider_Zip_Code__c AS [Zip Code]
, a.Phone
, a.Provider_Email__c AS Email
, a.Capacity__c AS [Licensed Capacity]
, insp.Date_of_Visit__c AS [Visit Date]
, inv.Statement_of_non_compliance_Issue_Date__c AS [Statement of Non-Compliance Issued Date]
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Inspection__c WHERE Type_of_Visit__c = 'Pre-Licensing') AS [Number of PreLicensing Statement of Non-Compliance issue date]

  FROM Inspection__c insp
  JOIN Account a ON a.Id = insp.Provider_No__c
  JOIN Investigation__c inv ON inv.Provider_Id__c = a.Id
  WHERE (insp.Date_of_Visit__c BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2018-11-30')
  AND (a.Record_Type_Name__c = 'Large Group' OR a.Record_Type_Name__c = 'Small Group')
  AND insp.Type_of_Visit__c IN ('Pre-Licensing',
    'Provisional License 90-day Monitoring',
    'Provisional License Renewal',
    'Renewal-Monitoring',
    'Renewal-Full Review',
    'Monitoring',
    'Enhanced Monitoring',
    'Capacity Increase',
    'Change of Location',
    'Change of Space',
    'Follow-up',
    'Monitoring outside differential Licensing Cycle',
    'License Upgrade',
    'Re-Activate Provider',
    'Technical Assistance',
    'Progress',
    'Renewal-Enhanced Monitoring')
```

I need to count each visit type for each provider and return the values into the table. It doesn't have to be a COUNT function if there's a better way.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: are you wanting a column for each count(typeofvisit) or each typeofvisit to be a separate row?

Comment: Separate columns. Thanks for the comment, edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to type out all your strings but I will show you how to do it.

Lets say your query looks like this:

```
SELECT A,B,C
FROM T
WHERE Z in ('x','y','z')
```

Where T has index index1 (in your case index1 is probably Provider_ID)

Then you can do this

```
SELECT A,B,C, G1.x_count, G1.y_count, G1.z_count
FROM T
JOIN (
  SELECT index1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Z = 'x' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS x_COUNT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Z = 'y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS y_COUNT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Z = 'z' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS z_COUNT
  FROM T
  WHERE Z in ('x','y','z')
  GROUP BY index1
) G1 on T.index1 = G1.index1
```

So now you have the counts for x, y, z for each index1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySql 8, you can use

```
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Type_of_Visit)
```

might solve your issue.